# Как извлечь из строки нужные данные?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть переменная с таким содержанием:

```
string(544) "
Seats: 11;12;
Name: qqqq;wwww;
Start: Прешов, АВ Košická 2725/2
End: Мукачево, АЗ Лавковская, 1б
Date: 2019-06-22
Time: 09:40 PM
"
```

Мне из всех этих данных нужно извлечь и сохранить

```
Seats: 11;12;
```

только без слова "Seats: ". В итоге, для дальнейшей работы, я хотел бы получить массив:

```
[0]=>11
[1]=>12
```

Перепробовал множество вариантов, не смог решить этот вопрос.

Вот последнее, что я смог сделать, но не работает:

```
$re = '/\s+([\d;]+)/';
$str = $item['meta'];
$wt_name = preg_split($re, $str);
```

Результат:

```
array(3) { [0]=>
string(260) "
Seats: 11;12;
Name: qqq;www;
Start: Прешов,
АВ Košická" [1]=>
string(111) "/2
End: Мукачево,
АЗ Лавковская,"
[2]=> string(166)
"б
Date: 2019-06-24
Time: 09:40 PM
" }
```

Пожалуйста, помогите написать правильное регулярное выражение

Answer (score 2):

зачем вы делаете `split`? вам нужен `preg_match` и если надо строку `seats` то и используйте ее в выражении

```
preg_match("/Seats: (.*);$/m", $txt, $matches);
```

должны получить искомые `11;12;` в `$matches[1]`, а дальше можете сделать `explode()` по разделителю `;`

Comment: Все верно, но только забыли добавить модификатор шаблона `m` для работы метасимволов `^`, `$` в многострочном контексте.

Comment: @Jigius добавил

Comment: @teran, спасибо за код. Сделал, как вы предложили, но var_dump($matches) показывает array(0){ }, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Вот этом примере https://regex101.com/r/PQt8Hz/2, вроде бы все правильно находит, только не понимаю, почему вырезает нужное, может быть и в моем случае он просто его вырезает?

Comment: @VladSiy, работает - как вам нужно.  [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cf10b173220a1d6971c45c4f2969ac2dc68d3c0f)

Answer (score 0):

> В итоге, для дальнейшей работы, я хотел бы получить массив:
>   `[0]=>11`
>   `[1]=>12`

```
$str = 'Seats: 11;12;
Name: qqqq;wwww;
Start: Прешов, АВ Košická 2725/2
End: Мукачево, АЗ Лавковская, 1б
Date: 2019-06-22
Time: 09:40 PM';

if (preg_match('~Seats:\h*(\d+);(\d+)~', $str, $arr)) {
    array_shift($arr);
}

var_dump($arr);
```

---

[**Демо PHP**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/33e9df952f38430f578a19c5b6185e3eecfbbeee)

Comment: мне кажется, что количество значений там произвольно

Comment: @teran не факт, ведь из первого поста это не становится очевидным.

Answer (score 0):

Всю работу можно выполнить в явном виде:

- Разделить входные данные на строки
- Разделить строки на ключ/значение

---

```
$str = "Seats: 11;12;
Name: qqqq;wwww;
Start: Прешов, АВ Košická 2725/2
End: Мукачево, АЗ Лавковская, 1б
Date: 2019-06-22
Time: 09:40 PM";

$lines = explode("\n", trim($str));
$data = array_reduce(array_filter($lines), function($res, $line){
    [$key, $value] = preg_split('#\s*:\s*#', $line, 2);
    $res[$key] = $value;
    return $res;
}, []);

var_dump($data);

// Далее, можно работать с полями, в зависимости от их назначения и формата
preg_match_all('#(\d+);#', $data['Seats'], $m);
var_dump($m[1]);
```

[3v4l](https://3v4l.org/2qeuO)

> ```
> array(6) {
>   ["Seats"]=>
>   string(6) "11;12;"
>   ["Name"]=>
>   string(10) "qqqq;wwww;"
>   ["Start"]=>
>   string(35) "Прешов, АВ Košická 2725/2"
>   ["End"]=>
>   string(48) "Мукачево, АЗ Лавковская, 1б"
>   ["Date"]=>
>   string(10) "2019-06-22"
>   ["Time"]=>
>   string(8) "09:40 PM"
> }
>
> array(2) {
>   [0]=>
>   string(2) "11"
>   [1]=>
>   string(2) "12"
> }
> ```

Comment: `explode` не проще юзать для начальной разбивки по двоеточию?

Comment: Всегда хочется меньше зависеть от наличия пробелов вокруг двоеточия..

Comment: @vp_arth спасибо за пример, он хорошо работает, как и все предложенные варианты, но только со статичными данными из примера. На сайте, почему-то не хочет работать. Стоит мне изменить на `$str = $item['meta'] ` получаю `array(0){ }`. Ничего не могу поделать. `$item['meta']` содержит строку, которую я опубликовал в вопросе.

Comment: `var_dump($item['meta'])`

Comment: `string(542) "
Seats: 37;38;
Name:
One;Two;
Start: Прешов,
АВ Košická
2725/2
End:
Мукачево, АЗ
Лавковская, 1б
Date: 2019-06-
25
Time: 09:40 PM
"`

Comment: Странно, потому что тут нет 542 байта. Можно `echo json_encode($item['meta'])`? Или вы удалили часть строки?

Comment: `"
Seats:
35;36;
Name:
ase;cew;
Start:
\u041f\u0440\u0435\u0448\u043e\u0432, \u0410\u0412
Ko\u0161ick\u00e1 2725\/2
End:
\u041c\u0443\u043a\u0430\u0447\u0435\u0432\u043e,
\u0410\u0417
\u041b\u0430\u0432\u043a\u043e\u0432\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f,
1\u0431
Date:
2019-06-25
Time:
09:40 PM"`

Comment: Т.е. переносов нет. Печаль. И всё равно тут только 158 байт, непонятно откуда 542. (И даже с этой строкой всё чудесным образом "работает", потому что explode не может вернуть пустой массив)

Answer (score 0):

Можно извлечь все числа, разделённые точкой с запятой после  `Seats:` с помощью одного регулярного выражения:

```
if (preg_match_all('~(?:\G(?!^);|Seats:\s*)\K\d+~',$txt,$matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

См. [пример кода в действии](https://3v4l.org/nflLs) и [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/a4XIX0/1).

**Подробности**

- `(?:\G(?!^);|Seats:\s*)` - конец предыдущего совпадения и точка с запятой или Seats: и 0+ пробельных символов
- `\K` - оператор, очищающий буфер целого совпадения
- `\d+` - 1 и более цифр.